# Thunar and ls different file size

Tags: files, ls, thunar

I have a complete android userdata partition image on disk and it shows 48.9 GiB on Thunar but only 3.8 GB in ls and Baobab. How is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please show the output of `du -h your_file` and `ls -lh your_file`

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the commands you ran and their respective outputs to illustrate the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a *sparse* file; i.e. a file that has "holes" where there really is nothing, just zeroes. Since you wrote that this was a disk partition, that is actually quite likely.

```
[sh @ balrog] .../work/test/sparse 24 % ls -lh
total 1.1M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sh 1000 1001M  5. Feb 2016  sparse-1MB.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sh 1000  8.0K 16. Jun 2020  sparse-8k
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sh 1000  8.0K 16. Jun 2020  sparse-8k-zero
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sh 1000 1000M  5. Feb 2016  sparse-zero.bin

[sh @ balrog] .../work/test/sparse 25 % ls -sh1
total 1.1M
1.0M sparse-1MB.bin
4.0K sparse-8k
   0 sparse-8k-zero
   0 sparse-zero.bin
```

Many file tools can't really handle them correctly. The problem is that those files really have two sizes: The nominal size (which is what `ls -l` and *Thunar* show you) and the true *allocated* size (which `du -h` or `ls -sh` show).

Be really careful when copying such a file; some tools may "fill" the holes and actually write zeroes where there used to be the hole, really consuming the nominal size. See also `man cp` and the `--sparse` option.

If you use that kind of files often, use [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat) which shows you both sizes at once:

[image: QDirStat showing sparse files]

Comment: Thanks. Just one question, what is the space really left of disk ?

Comment: @darkon11 On filesystems that support it e.g. EXT4 empty bytes in sparse files are not stored physically on disk but rather in the file's meta-data (description on the filesystem) and generated dynamically when the file is being read and therefore they don’t occupy actual disk blocks and the space actually used on disk should be what `du` reports and the rest is considered free … See more info https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file … If the above answer solves your question, please consider accepting it by selecting the check mark next to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers.